# Twelve different dice are rolled. What is the probability that each of the numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6} occurs at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

I ended up getting $$\frac{C(11,7)}{6^{12}}$$

$C(11,7)$ was obtained using the number of k-combinations with repetition, where at least one object from each of n different types of objects is chosen.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: No.  What do you think $C(11,7)$ is counting?  The ways to select $7$ dice from a set of $11$ to be *what*?

Comment: At first I thought it was the way to distribute 12 dice to 6 positions with at least 1 of every number, but now I'm realizing that doesn't work at all or make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion

The complementary event is to have *at least* one face not show among the 12 rolls.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling numbers (these encapsulate PIE):

$${12\brace 6} \times 6! \times \frac{1}{6^{12}} = {\frac {1654565}{3779136}}
\approx 0.4378156806.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ let $E_i$ denote the event that number $i$ does *not* occur.

Then to be found is: $$1-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^6E_i\right)$$This can be found by applying the [principle of inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and also symmetry.